# gulp tasks browserSync or nodemon not refresh page content in production mode

Tags: gulp, production-environment, browser-sync, nodemon

I have two gulp tasks for refreshing browser and restarting backend server when files are changed:

```
gulp.task('watchtemplates', gulp.series('dosomethingwithtemplates', browserReload));
```

and another task just to reload server. Nodemon has the following options:

```
"nodemon"             : {
                "script"   : "bin.js",
                "env"      : {
                    "NODE_PATH" : ".",
                    'NODE_ENV'  : isProduction ? 'production' : 'development'
                },
                "delay"    : 2,
                "nodeArgs" : [ "--debug" ],
                "watch"    : [ "bin/*.js"" ]
            }
```

Everything is refreshed in development mode, but once I change the mode to production, browserSync shows me that he refreshed the page but content stays the same(((
Somebody maybe knows why content is not refreshed?

Comment: I believe it is a feature of nodemon to not restart the server in production becuase it *is* production. There should be no need to restart it.

Comment: I think about but why there is no documentation about it? How can I test production mode with refreshing? I have two views for error page. I can not test error page for production with nodemon(((

Comment: @ovod I have exactly the same problem for the same reason. Did you figure it out?